# Open API Schema for an array of arrays

Tags: java, swagger, openapi, quarkus

I'm going to define Open Api schema for an endpoint implemented in JAVA, which returns JSON like this:

```
{"id": 1, "data": [[int, int]]}
```

Any idea how to configue the annotation @Schema?